# Softek Barcode Reader Issues - Barcode don´t read correctly on a different computer

Tags: c#, .net, barcode

We have a custom-built imaging application that includes barcode recognition capabilities. We use softek barcode reader API as our recognition codec, and until now, everthing was working fine.

However, recently we sold that application to one of our clients. We deployed it, and we were struck with the fact that the barcode reader simply stopped working **rigth**. It still "works" on a way, but on the client´s machines, it returns random values (and by random, i mean REALLY random. "05020018" Becomes "16Y", then "4848", then "1024"...) Each read there gives back a different value. Most of the times the value is shorter that it should be, and while the codebar only contains numbers, it oftens gives back letters when i read it.

The software works using a recular (tabletop) scanner. The document is captured and sent to a webservice that stores it on a remote server. Each document have a barcode which stores the "place" that it should be stored on the server. It is normally a long number (24 digits), coding all the relevant information about the document in a custom-made format. Every character is numeric.

The SAME software with the SAME configs on another ambiente works perfectly.

What could be happening? Could it be machine architecture or something else?

Is not the scanner. The same device works on most machines but not on the troublesome one.

.NET 3.5!

Thanks in advance!

** EDIT **

Just to clarify it more, there is not a barcode reader *device*, just a coding API developed by softek. Their documentation was no help, and I can´t contact them either. Searching for this problem on google didn´t give any results, too.

The configuration for the recognition API are done on our software and stored on the database. We use the same dabatase (same server, same data) on my workplace and the software works fine, so it´s not a software configuration issue, it seens. May it be a conflict with some local, exotic software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked with other barcode readers in the past, but never Softek. I would suggest that the barcode reader is in some sort of configure mode, that every read is setting some sort of config option.

1. Try resetting the barcode reader with config codes which are normally in the manual
2. Is the client scanning different barcodes ( codes specific to them or that they generated) then your other customers?

Comment: I think i didn´t explain it rigth. I will clarify the question.

Comment: There, claryfied. We don´t use a barcode reader _device_, just an coding API. The imaging device is a regular scanner. Sorry for not including that at first!

Comment: My next guess would be orientation of the document. Is the paper tilted and is the scanner reading/scanning it properly?

Are you able to swap out the hardware scanner for another one? 
Is it possible the hardware or firmware is bad or out of date?

Comment: Yeah, it was the page orientation. That one scanner was using a hardware page-flip config that was bugging my barcode detection! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same behaviour with actual barcode readers (ie: using the device, not an API) because the language of the device was set incorrectly. Windows treats the scanner as a keyboard so check the language by going to Control Panel -> Region and Language settings -> Keyboards and Languages -> Change keyboards button -> Installed services panel.